# Jquery, ajax call on submit is hitting the success, but I am getting a 200 OK

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code:

```js
$("#contact-form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".bg-danger").hide();
  $(".bg-success").hide();
  var data = $('#contact-form').serialize();
  console.log("Meow?");
  
  $.ajax({
    url: "api.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result) {
      console.log("Here?");
      console.log(result);
      console.log(gettype(result));
      
      if (result == "success") {
        $(".bg-success").show();
      } else {
        $(".bg-danger").show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The ajax call does make a call to api.php which returns "success" or "error", but anything in my success method is being called, I am not getting any console logs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So add an error handler and see if it is being called `error : function (x, status, error){ console.log(status, error); }`

Comment: My guess is you are not returning valid JSON since you are telling it you are getting back JSON. `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Time to do some debugging.  When you open your browser's debugging tools and observe the AJAX request on the network tab, does the response contain what you expect?  Are there any errors at all in the response?  Any errors at all on the debugging console?  Using the script debugger, is this submit handler invoked in the first place?  Is the success handler invoked?  What specifically happens?

Comment: If you're not getting the console logs, why does the title say it's hitting the success? Did you mean to say **not** hitting the success?